# Use global variable in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use like a global variable but don't know how to do it yet in Scala Spark.

I want to do a map over a RDD calling a function as you can see here:

```
  var flag = 0
  df1 = rdd1.map(x => function_1(x, df1, flag))
```

the function is the following:

```
 def function_1(input: Tuple2[String, String], df: DataFrame, flag: int)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    var dfend = df
    if (flag.equals(0)){
      val someDF = Seq((input._2, "name")).toDF("gr", "tgr")
      dfend = df.union(someDF)
      flag = 1
    }
    dfend
  }
```

**As you can see, I am trying to use a flag to only do the if condition the first time in the map and in the following times don't do it because is changed to 1.**
But this is not working, how could I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some reproducible example to understand it better? What is df1? What is the output that you are expecting based on the input data that you might have?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid using global variables. Instead, I would suggest you to use `zipWithIndex()` which will create a tuple consists of the original row and the row index which you can use for your business logic.

In the following example, only the first element will be printed:

```
def returnOnlyTheFirst(index: Long, row: Row): Unit = {
  if (index == 0L) {
    println(row)
    row
  }
}

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("XX", "YY", "ZZ", "TT")).toDF("name")
df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map { case (row: Row, idx: Long) => returnOnlyTheFirst(idx, row)}.collect()

// Output: `[xx]`
```